# Flutter AppLifecycleState.resumed does not detect app open (Android onStart)

Tags: flutter

According to the [flutter AppLifecycleState documentation](https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html):

> resumed → The application is visible and responding to user input

But It seems **not to detect app opening**.

I have implemented the `AppLifecycleState` in the `main.dart`:

```
SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) {
    switch (msg) {
      case 'AppLifecycleState.paused':
        {
          function...
        }
        break;
      case 'AppLifecycleState.resumed':
        {
          function...
        }
        break;
    }
    return Future.value();
  });
```

How to check whether an application becomes in Foreground in Flutter (based on resume and app open)?

Comment: Got any solution?

Comment: Nothing so far :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the built in lifecycle management does not provide a app-open event, but this is how we do it.

We define our own enum that replicates the `AppLifecycleState` where we add `opened`:

```
/// see [AppLifecycleState] but added [opened]
enum AppState {
  opened, // <--
  resumed,
  paused,
  inactive,
  detached,
}
```

Then we define a widget that uses `initialState` to trigger the `opened` event and use the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixing to detect the other changes.

```
class AppLifecycleTracker extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final void Function(AppState state) didChangeAppState;

  const AppLifecycleTracker({
    Key? key,
    required this.didChangeAppState,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppLifecycleTracker> createState() => _AppLifecycleTrackerState();
}

class _AppLifecycleTrackerState extends State<AppLifecycleTracker>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.didChangeAppState(AppState.opened);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    AppState s;
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        s = AppState.resumed;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        s = AppState.inactive;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        s = AppState.paused;
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        s = AppState.detached;
        break;
    }
    widget.didChangeAppState(state);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

Then be sure to add it at the very top of the widget tree to prevent it from being re-rendered (otherwise it would trigger the `opened` event again:

```
runApp(
  AppLifecycleTracker(
    didChangeAppState: (state) => log(state.name),
    child: ...,
  )
);
```

Comment: does it work with iOS?

Comment: @Balaji yes it is independent of the platform.

Answer (score 2):

```
  class LifeCycleManager extends StatefulWidget {
   final Widget child;
     LifeCycleManager({required this.child});

   _LifeCycleManagerState createState() => _LifeCycleManagerState();
    }

      class _LifeCycleManagerState extends State<LifeCycleManager>
         with WidgetsBindingObserver {
      
       @override
      void initState() {
       WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
       super.initState();
      }

     @override
    void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
 }

    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
      
     super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.detached) {

    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
 
    }
    }

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
     child: widget.child,
       );
      }
```

wrap you main materialapp with lifecycle manager widget and in life cycle manger you can set condition according to your requirements and perform. specific tasks according to that

Comment: But how does it help to detect app open? (onStart and onResume in lifecycle) https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onstart